# How to retry requests using MS JAVA SDK for GRAPH API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am a beginner using Graph API and currently trying to handle throttling related errors in my code. In the sdk's github page there is a RetryHandler class. But i can't seem to find an implementation of the code for a sample request. Is there any examples which i can inspect and try?

As an example i can give my own code below.

```
@Override
public JsonObject getUserList(String accessToken){
    LOGGER.trace("Querying directRoutingEnabled users");
    final String selectQuery = "mail,givenName,surname,displayName";
    final List<Option> requestOptions = new LinkedList<>();
    final String filterQuery = createFilterQuery();

    requestOptions.add(new HeaderOption(CONSISTENCY_LEVEL, EVENTUAL));
    requestOptions.add(new QueryOption(SELECT, selectQuery));
    requestOptions.add(new QueryOption(COUNT, true));
    requestOptions.add(new QueryOption(FILTER, filterQuery));

    IGraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(new SimpleAuthProvider(accessToken)).buildClient();
    IUserCollectionRequest request = graphServiceClient
            .users()
            .buildRequest(requestOptions);
    IUserCollectionPage users = request.get();
    return users.getRawObject();
}
```

How can i cover this code with **retry-after mechanism (and maybe also Error Handling) using Graph SDK for Java?**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default middleware from the core library comes with the default RetryHandler implementation. And thanks to a [recent fix](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-core/issues/160), it works with throttling errors as well.

Starting from V3 of the SDK, you can specify custom OkHttpClient with custom interceptors. Customization guidelines can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/customize-client?tabs=java.

Default RetryHandler implementation: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-core/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/graph/httpcore/RetryHandler.java

Default RetryHandler design: https://microsoftgraph.github.io/msgraph-sdk-design/middleware/RetryHandler.html

Comment: In addition to all this good information, the java SDK offers fluent methods for select, orderby, count, expand... see the documentation. It should allow you to write less code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-requests?tabs=java#retrieve-a-list-of-entities

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But i was also wondering how to use this handler. For example should i use a try catch block and handle throttling at catch? Is there any examples for me to view and maybe try other than default RetryHandler implementation? I believe i understood the concept but actual implementation is still confusing for me.

Comment: @azb.1 Were you ever able to figure out how to use the retry handler? The examples online for Java on utilizing RetryHandler isn't very helpful.